# The use of the word "equity" to mean "average?

Tags: word-usage

The map below is of CO₂ emissions (from [Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/share-co2-emissions)). It labels countries as being either "Below global equity" or "Above global equity".

[image]

Here the word "equity" seems to have been used to mean "(world) average". Is such usage correct/common/acceptable?

Comment: the authors opinioned definition of equity is in the article you cite: 'Countries in red have per capita emissions above global 'equity' (meaning they emit more than their population share); those in blue are below the global average.'

Answer (score 2):

Here, *equity* is treated as ***allowed fair level*** of CO<sub>2</sub> to be emitted (by any country).

*"Above global equity"* = *Above fair level*

*"Below global equity"* = *Below fair level*

Global Carbon Project (G.C.P) or any respective international organization might have agreed upon on some fair level of CO<sub>2</sub> emission i.e. allowed level of CO<sub>2</sub> emission.

So, the countries in the red are emitting CO<sub>2</sub> than ***above fair level.*** Whereas, the countries in the blue are emitting CO<sub>2</sub> than ***below fair level***.

**Equity** according to [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/equity) is

> Meaning (**Entry 1**): The quality of being fair and impartial.
>
> > Usage: The focus here has rarely been on equity or on a fair deal for the poor